# Order by with a condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables, `Products` and `Category`. each `product` is related to a specific `Category`, and has an `Expiry_Date` which may be `NULL` value.

I want to query all `products`ordered by the soonest `Expiry_Date` first. Null-Expiry_date products are ordered last for a `Category` with specific name, like `Food`.

### UPDATED (sample data below):

Product table:

[image]

Category Table:

[image]

Results:

[image]

Comment: Sample data and desired results are recommended.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: ["as formatted text"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)... You seem to be *excluding* some rows, this isn't just about ordering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't just about ordering, you want to exclude some rows with null dates but include others based on the category name; and then order what's left:

```
select p.prod_id, p.name, p.expiry_date, c.cat_id
from product p
join category c on c.cat_id = p.cat_id
where (c.name = 'Food' or p.expiry_date is not null)
order by p.expiry_date desc nulls last;
```

The `where` clause excludes products will null expiry dates, unless they are in the category called 'Food'. The order-by is then straightforward, though as you want it in descending date order you need to [specify `nulls last`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#i2171079) to get those... er... last.

Demo with your sample data in CTEs:

```
with product (prod_id, name, expiry_date, cat_id) as (
  select 1, 'NAME1', date '2018-01-10', 1 from dual
  union all select 2, 'NAME2', date '2018-01-11', 2 from dual
  union all select 3, 'NAME3', date '2018-01-12', 3 from dual
  union all select 4, 'NAME4', null, 1 from dual
  union all select 5, 'NAME5', null, 2 from dual
  union all select 6, 'NAME6', date '2018-01-13', 2 from dual
  union all select 7, 'NAME7', date '2018-01-14', 2 from dual
  union all select 8, 'NAME8', null, 3 from dual
),
category (cat_id, name) as (
  select 1, 'Food' from dual
  union all select 2, 'Food1' from dual
  union all select 3, 'Food2' from dual
)
select p.prod_id, p.name, p.expiry_date, c.cat_id
from product p
join category c on c.cat_id = p.cat_id
where (c.name = 'Food' or p.expiry_date is not null)
order by p.expiry_date desc nulls last;

   PROD_ID NAME  EXPIRY_DAT     CAT_ID
---------- ----- ---------- ----------
         7 NAME7 2018-01-14          2
         6 NAME6 2018-01-13          2
         3 NAME3 2018-01-12          3
         2 NAME2 2018-01-11          2
         1 NAME1 2018-01-10          1
         4 NAME4                     1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, just use `nulls last` in the `order by`:

```
select c.category, p.*
from products p join
     category c
     on p.? = c.?  -- whatever the join keys are
order by category, expiry_date nulls last
```

Comment: As a note: *NULLS LAST is the default for ascending order* in Oracle.

Comment: thanks for you, but the products which have a null Expiry_date, must be related to a specific Category, like `Food`.